# Cannot run commands like "shardCollection" or "enableSharding"

Tags: .net, mongodb-.net-driver

I inherited a project to maintain. Apparently there was a decision to switch from CosmosDb to dedicated MongoDb. There is a project in a CI pipeline that seeds mongo database with collections and creates indexes. Now it is done with commands like that:

```cs
var partition = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"shardCollection", $"{databaseName}.{collectionName}"},
    { "key", new Dictionary<string, object>() { { $"{indexName}", "hashed" } } }
};
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(partition);
var response = adminDb.RunCommand(command);
```

This does not work on my machine - I am getting `Command shardCollection failes: no such command 'shardCollection'.`

[image]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I found examples of that code elsewhere as a working code and I am very confused.

#### Update 1

I also tried to run this command before trying to set sharding on my collections:

```cs
var shardDbResult = adminDatabase.RunCommand<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument>(
    new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument() { 
        { "enableSharding", $"{databaseName}" } 
 });
```

but I also get a similar error `Command enableSharding failes: no such command 'enableSharding'`. I even tried that from `mongosh`[image]:

#### Update 2

So eventually I figured this might be something with my MongoDb installation. So I decided to start a sharded replica set in docker, which apparently I managed to run.
Now the command:

```
db.adminCommand({enableSharding: "<databaseName>"})
```

works fine (at least it prints the report: `ok: 1`). Also this command works fine:

```
db.adminCommand({shardCollection: "<databaseName>.<collectionName>", key: {<fieldName>: 1}})
```

But my code from the top of the question continuously fails with the same message...

Versions:

- OS Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2
- .net 5 (5.0.15)
- MongoDb 5.0
- Mongo.Bson nuget 2.15.0
- Mongo.Driver nuget 2.15.0
- Mongo.DriverCore nuget 2.15.0

Comment: try enableSharding before: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/enableSharding/. NOTE: you can't rely (it may or may not) that cosmosdb commands will be successfully called in mongodb and vise verse.

Comment: I tried that, please check my updated question. I am beginning to think this has something to do with my machine...

Comment: what is result of this command: `{ isMaster : 1 }`?

Comment: I tried running the command from my .net console app - it runs, returns a bunch of key-value pairs. Among them is `isMaster=true`, `secondary=false`,the host address of the primary and current host address (they are the same). Also `setName=mongors1`, `setVersion=2`, `hosts=[mongors1n1:27017,mongors1n2:27017,mongors1n3:27017]` (which are correct), `readonly=false` and `ok=1`. I tried executing the commands in question after running `isMaster` command, but I still get the same error.

Comment: your env is replica set (since it contains `setName`) but you're running commands for sharded cluster, this is why you see command not found exception

Comment: I finally found a properly set up replica set with sharding and it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a totally wrong set my replica set with sharding cluster. Once I used the instructions for deploying mongodb sharded cluster from [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68552274/3239998), my code started working.